# Nested if-then-else statements

Tags: ifthenelse

I try to use nested if-then-else conditions:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand{\printTrueOrFalseA}[1]{%
   \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{true}}{true}{false}%
}

\newcommand{\True}{true}
\newcommand{\False}{false}

\newcommand{\printTrueOrFalseB}[1]{%
   \ifx#1\True true\else false\fi%
}

\begin{document}
\printTrueOrFalseA{\printTrueOrFalseA{true}} % produces an error
\printTrueOrFalseB{\printTrueOrFalseB{true}} % produces the unexpected  result "false"
\end{document}
```

When I use the `\ifthenelse` command, my code produces an error:

```
! Argument of \equal has an extra }.<inserted text>\par \printTrueOrFalseA{\printTrueOrFalseA{true}}
! Paragraph ended before \equal was complete.<to be read again>\par \printTrueOrFalseA{\printTrueOrFalseA{true}}
```

I would expect the result `true` in both cases. Why does it not work as I would expect?

Answer (score 2):

Your `\printTrueOrFalseA{\printTrueOrFalseA{true}}` becomes

```
\ifthenelse{\equal{\printTrueOrFalseA{true}}{true}{true}{false}
```

but the argument to `\equal` is illegal, because `\ifthenelse` is not fully expandable, hence you get an error.

Your `\printTrueOrFalseB{\printTrueOrFalseB{true}}` becomes

```
\ifx\printTrueOrFalseB{true}\True true\else false\fi
```

which compares `\printTrueOrFalseB` with `{`, returning false; the tokens `true}\True true` vanish because they constitute the “true branch” for `\ifx`. This expands to `false\fi` and then `\fi` vanishes, leaving just “false” as printout.

Answer (score 1):

here is how you could do it (without `\ifthenelse`)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\printTrueOrFalseC}[1]{%
   \romannumeral
   \if\pdfstrcmp{#1}{true}0%
        \expandafter\@firstoftwo
   \else\expandafter\@secondoftwo
   \fi
   {\z@ true}{\z@ false}%
}

\makeatother
\begin{document}

\huge
\printTrueOrFalseC{\printTrueOrFalseC{\printTrueOrFalseC{\printTrueOrFalseC{\printTrueOrFalseC{\printTrueOrFalseC{true}}}}}}

\printTrueOrFalseC{\printTrueOrFalseC{\printTrueOrFalseC{\printTrueOrFalseC{\printTrueOrFalseC{\printTrueOrFalseC{True}}}}}}% test checks for "true", not "True"
\end{document}
```

[image]