# \ifthenelse as an argument to \equal

Tags: macros, ifthenelse

In this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand{\objtitle}[1]{%                                                                                                                   
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{a}}{avalue}{}%                                                                                                         
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{b}}{bvalue}{}%                                                                                                         
}

\newcommand{\counterpart}[1]{%                                                                                                                
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{a}}{b}{}%                                                                                                              
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{b}}{a}{}%                                                                                                              
}
\begin{document}
\counterpart{a}
\objtitle{a}
\objtitle{\counterpart{a}}
\end{document}
```

`\counterpart{a}` and `\objtitle{a}` work separately but `\objtitle{\counterpart{a}}` produces and error:

```
! Argument of \equal has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.17 \objtitle{\counterpart{a}}
```

Using `\objtitle{\protect\counterpart{a}}` eliminates the error message but produces no output.

What is the problem and how to solve?

Comment: `\ifthenelse` is (very) fragile and can not be used in the argument of `\equal`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle using `\protect` produces no output. Is there a solution?

Comment: yes `\protect` makes it safe but stops it executing at all so it will not be equal to anything. You do not want to use `\ifthenelse` at all, but you havn't given any description of what you actually want to do so not sure what to suggest.

Comment: related https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451960/nested-if-then-else-statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\ifthenelse` *cannot* be used nested. No way. Sorry, it's impossible.

If you want to do nestable case switching, you need to use more advanced tools.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\caseswitch}{O{}mm}
 {
  \str_case_e:nnF { #2 } { #3 } { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\objtitle}[1]{%
  \caseswitch{#1}{
   {a}{avalue}
   {b}{bvalue}
  }%
}

\newcommand{\counterpart}[1]{%
  \caseswitch{#1}{
    {a}{b}
    {b}{a}
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\counterpart{a}

\objtitle{a}

\objtitle{\counterpart{a}}

\end{document}
```

You can also call `\caseswitch` with an optional argument; thus

```
\caseswitch[none of the above]{#1}{
   {a}{avalue}
   {b}{bvalue}
  }
```

would return “none of the above” if `#1` is neither `a` nor `b`. With no optional argument, no match returns nothing.

The number of cases is arbitrary.