# Can I nest the \newcommand command with itself?

Tags: macros

Currently, I want to define a command that makes it easy for me to write the usual notation for a set in set theory. Using the `\newcommand` command, I was able to define the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\TCConjunto}[2]{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}\AND\equal{#2}{}}%
{\varnothing}%
{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}%
{\{#2\}}%
{\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}%
{\{#1\}}%
{\{#1\,:\,#2\}}%
}%
}%
}%

%%-----

\newcommand{\TCUnion}[2]{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}\AND\equal{#2}{}}%
{\varnothing}%
{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}%
{#2}%
{\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}%
{#1}%
{#1\cup #2}%
}%
}%
}%

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

$\TCConjunto{}{}$

$\TCConjunto{A,B,C}{}$

$\TCConjunto{}{A,B,C}$

$\TCUnion{}{}$

$\TCUnion{A}{}$

$\TCUnion{}{B}$

$\TCUnion{A}{B}$

%%%%%%$\TCUnion{A}{\TCUnion{B}{C}}$

\end{document}
```

The commands I just mentioned work with "simple" parameters. In a line of code, I've used the `%` symbol to highlight a problem; when I try to nest one of those commands with itself it throws an error. Could you help me figure out the problem?

Comment: Don't you get an error even before that?

Comment: all those blank lines in the definition are end of paragraph which is not allowed in math.

Comment: I'm a little curious, why not just use `\cup` and `\varnothing` normally, without defining new commands? In addition to introducing potential errors you have to fix like the one here, I would imagine that defining commands with long names would cause clutter and affect how easy it is to read your own code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never been a user of the `ifthen` package, but I'm quite partial to using plain TeX conditionals. With these conditionals, you can nest `\TCConjunto` and `\TCUnion` as much as you want.

[image: Screenshot of the output of the LaTeX code shown below.]

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand{\TCConjunto}[2]{
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax
      \varnothing%
    \else
      \{#2\}%
    \fi
  \else
    \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax
      \{#1\}%
    \else
      \{#1\,:\,#2\}%
    \fi
  \fi
}

%%-----

\newcommand{\TCUnion}[2]{
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax
      \varnothing%
    \else
      #2%
    \fi
  \else
    \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax
      #1%
    \else
      #1\cup#2%
    \fi
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % to make the screenshot look prettier

$\TCConjunto{}{}$

$\TCConjunto{A,B,C}{}$

$\TCConjunto{}{A,B,C}$

$\TCConjunto{A}{B}$

$\TCUnion{}{}$

$\TCUnion{A}{}$

$\TCUnion{}{B}$

$\TCUnion{A}{B}$

$\TCUnion{\TCUnion{A}{\TCUnion{B}{\TCConjunto{C}{D}}}}{E}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: It worked perfectly! Although I would like to know the reason for the error in the initial code. At first glance I would say that everything is fine, but it throws an error and I don't understand the reason. I am new to using conditionals in LaTeX and am not familiar with the \relax command. Why does the \detokenize{} command have to be in the middle of two \relax commands? I'm new and want to be aware of everything I use in the code.

Comment: @Darkmaster I'm happy this helped, and it's awesome that you're trying to learn LaTeX! :) For your first question, I prefer to use raw plain TeX conditionals, but these can be tricky for beginners, so the `ifthen` package wraps them with `\ifthenelse` to make conditionals easier to use. Because I personally don't use the `ifthen` package, I'm not the best person to explain, but it seems that [you can't put an `\ifthenelse` inside the condition of another `\ifthenelse` because it messes with TeX's expansion.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/451960)

Comment: As for your second question, `\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax` checks whether `#1` is empty. Here's how it works: `\detokenize` reads its argument as raw tokens of text. An empty `#1` has no tokens, so `\detokenize` will simply vanish if this happens, turning our if-statement into `\if\relax\relax`. Because `\if` compares if the next two items are the same after expansion, this condition is true. (In contrast, if `#1` *weren't* empty, then `\detokenize` wouldn't vanish; it'd turn into something else. And because `\relax` and "something else" aren't the same, the condition would be false.)

Answer (score 3):

If it's not too late to change syntax, I advocate an optional argument for `\TCConjunto`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewDocumentCommand{\TCConjunto}{om}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{%
    \IfBlankTF{#2}{\emptyset}{\{#2\}}
  }{\{#1:#2\}}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\TCUnion}{mm}{%
  \IfBlankTF{#1}{%
    \IfBlankTF{#2}{\emptyset}{#2}%
  }{%
    \IfBlankTF{#2}{#1}{#1\cup#2}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

$\TCConjunto{}$

$\TCConjunto{A,B,C}$

$\TCConjunto[x]{x\notin x}$

$\TCUnion{}{}$

$\TCUnion{A}{}$

$\TCUnion{}{B}$

$\TCUnion{A}{B}$

$\TCUnion{A}{\TCUnion{B}{C}}$

\end{document}
```

Sorry for `\emptyset`, but my eyes bleed when I see the plumber's symbol `\varnothing` used for the empty set.

[image]

With `\IfNoValueTF` we check whether the optional argument is present; with `\IfBlankTF` we check whether the supplied argument is empty (better, consists only of zero or more blank spaces).